# How to test an outbound messages with C sharp listener?

Tags: c#, wsdl, workflowoutboundmessage

I have a C# application I set up as a listener for outbound messages, but I'm getting a 403 error response in Salesforce. Do I need to setup a valid endpoint to the asmx file? If so, how do I do I go about that? Is there some other authentication or something I'm missing?

Comment: It sounds like your application is expecting authentication. You'll need to check your server's configuration.

Comment: Is your request actually reaching your listener? It might be something else rejecting the request before it event gets to your server.

Comment: I'm not entirely sure. I was using this sample https://developer.salesforce.com/page/Creating_an_Outbound_Messaging_Notification_Service_with_CSharp_and_.Net_Framework_2.0#Setting_up_for_testing_in_Visual_Studio.

Comment: I'm not sure how to test it.

Answer (score 1):

You will need to make sure that your .NET application that is going to process the Outbound messages is accessible to the Salesforce servers.

Assuming you are developing this on a company network this typically means two things:

- You will need a network admin to give you a public facing IP address and port that will go to the internal network ID and port that you are hosting the service at. In my case the network admin tells me a public IP address and port that redirects to my dev machines static IP address.
- The network admin may also need to allow inbound calls from the Salesforce IP addresses. See [What are the Salesforce network IP addresses that I need to whitelist?](https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=000003652&type=1)

Of course, this could all vary based on your network setup. In short, there needs to be a path that the Salesforce Servers can call a public IP address (or URL) that will find it's way to where you are hosting the web service.

You can't, for instance, tell Salesforce to send the outbound message to `http://localhost:1215/OM_Sample/AccountNotificationService.asmx`. From the perspective of the Salesforce servers that is the server itself, which makes no sense.